# Pandas to datetime check format

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have several csv files which all have a column with a date which is either in DD/MM/YYYY format or MM/DD/YYYY format.

At the moment I manually check the file and convert it the column to pandas datetime using the code below.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

In cases of different date format I change dayfirst=True/False.
I have to coerce errors as some rows contain dirty data.
I would like to automate this process so that I only upload the file and pandas will automatically decide if the column is in MM/DD or DD/MM format.

Any tips and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything? In general, I would think about how to get "clean" input data in the first place. Consider a date like '10/10/2019' - that is simply ambiguous. `pandas` can't automagically decide the position of month and day for you. Is the month/day position at least constant in one column or does it change randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found something that is working:

```
for df in df_list:
    df_test=df["Date"].str.split("/", expand=True)
    df_test[0] = pd.to_numeric(df_test[0], errors="coerce")
    df_test[1] = pd.to_numeric(df_test[1], errors="coerce")
    a=df_test[0].max()
    b=df_test[1].max()
    if b > a:
        df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Creation Date"],dayfirst=False, errors='coerce')
    elif a > b:
        df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Creation Date"],dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```